TestNG is not showing when running a test case even though it's installed
Test NG is not showing when running a test case
I need solution for this , I tried various things still it's not working, even I tried removing cucumber plugin as well still I am facing the same issue can anyone help me out with this

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
